# how do I check if an image file exists, and setting it as src of a variable asynchronously using pure js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a peace of code that looks through an array and adds each unique item. it then adds the that array item to the page. when it adds the item it looks up an image in a file, the image has the name off the id of the array item

not every item has an associated image but it needs to show an image. the problem with this method is it checks for each file synchronously and 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.' is there a way to do this differently to avoid this warning and the effect on the time it takes to load. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and don't really understand asynchronous operations. if anyone would be able to help that would be greatly appreciated.
if this doesn't make sense just let me know and I'll try to clarify.

```
<script>
//so variable can be used to refer to array locations, made it easier to compare everything
array_id = 0;
array_primery = 1;
array_name = 2;
array_range = 3;
array_type = 4;
array_gender = 5;
array_size = 6;
array_color = 7;
array_price = 8;
array_state = 9;
array_stock = 10;
array_accent1 = 11;
array_accent2 = 12;
array_description = 13;
function doesFileExist(urlToFile){ 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest (); 
    xhr.open ('HEAD', urlToFile, false); 
    xhr.send (); if (xhr.status == "404") { 
        //console.log ("File doesn't exist"); 
        return false ; 
    } else { 
        //console.log ("File exists"); 
        return true ; 
    } 
}
function findreplace(prodlist,id,url1,url2){
    
    for(const subprod in prodlist){
        if (prodlist[subprod][array_color] == prodlist[id][array_color] && prodlist[subprod][array_name] == prodlist[id][array_name] && prodlist[subprod][array_type] == prodlist[id][array_type] && prodlist[subprod][array_gender] == prodlist[id][array_gender]){
            if(doesFileExist(url1+prodlist[subprod][array_id]+url2)){
                return url1+prodlist[subprod][array_id]+url2;
            } 
        }
    }
    return url1+'null'+url2;
}
prodlist = {<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produnct_list";
    $result = mysqli_query($prod,$sql); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1){
        $x = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $y=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            if((isset($_GET['range']) && str_replace("_"," ", $_GET['range']) == $row['product_range']) || !isset($_GET['range'])){
                echo "prod".$row['product_id'].' : [';
                echo '"'.$row['product_id'].'",';      //  0  id
                echo '"'.$row['product_primery'].'",'; //  1  primery
                echo '"'.$row['product_name'].'",';    //  2  name
                echo '"'.$row['product_range'].'",';   //  3  range 
                echo '"'.$row['product_type'].'",';    //  4  type
                echo '"'.$row['product_gender'].'",';  //  5  gender
                echo '"'.$row['product_size'].'",';    //  6  size
                echo '"'.$row['product_color'].'",';   //  7  colour
                echo '"'.$row['product_price'].'",';   //  8  price
                echo '"'.$row['product_state'].'",';   //  9  state
                echo '"'.$row['product_stock'].'",';    //  10 stock
                echo '"'.$row['accent_1'].'",';   //  11  accent colour 1
                echo '"'.$row['accent_2'].'",';    //  12 accent colour 2
                echo '"'.$row['product_description'].'"';    //  12 accent colour 2
                echo ']';
                if($y < $x){echo',';}
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
};
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
var currentscrolltop = elmnt.scrollTop;
var page = window.innerHeight;


var put = document.getElementById('prodlist');
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){echo'var loged = true;';}else{echo'var 
loged = false;';}?>

}
load();

function load(){
    while (put.firstChild) {
        put.removeChild(put.firstChild);
    }   
    var itemsload = 0;
    if(document.getElementById('searchbox').value !== ''){
        loadwithsearch();
    }else{
        var prod_array = [];
        for(const subprod in prodlist){
        if (prodlist[subprod][array_stock]>0){
            var currentcolor = prodlist[subprod][array_name]+prodlist[subprod][array_color];
            if(prod_array.indexOf(currentcolor) == -1 && ((prodlist[subprod][array_state] == 'V' && loged == true) || prodlist[subprod][array_state] !== 'V') && pass(subprod,'size') && pass(subprod,'colour') && pass(subprod,'type') && pass(subprod,'gender') && prodlist[subprod][array_stock]>0){
                addprod(subprod);
                prod_array.push(prodlist[subprod][array_name]+prodlist[subprod][array_color]);
                itemsload = itemsload + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(itemsload == 0){
    noitems()
}
}

}

function pass(id,doing){
    //validate if filters are active and if so weather the products match the filter the id it the current item and doing is the filter its matching for
}
```

the code above loads() goes through the list adding products with unique name and colour, and the code bellow adds them to the div 'put'

```
    function addprod(id){ //id is the name of the array in the group exaple 'prod72'
        var productParentDiv = document.createElement('div');
        productParentDiv.classList = 'productparentdiv';
        productParentDiv.id = prodlist[id][array_id];
        //alert(prodlist[id][array_accent1]);
        if(prodlist[id][array_accent1].includes('#')){ //checks if it has an accent color set 
            productParentDiv.style.backgroundColor = prodlist[id] [array_accent1]; //makes the accent color the background color
        }

        //this is the current method for testing to find and then load in the images
        if(doesFileExist('assets/hero_images/'+prodlist[id][array_id]+'.png')){ //id image matching id exists 
            productParentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/hero_images/"+prodlist[id][array_id]+".png')"; //is set as background
        }else{
            productParentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+findreplace(prodlist,id,"assets/hero_images/",".png")+"')"; sets it to be the resault of the function findreplace() that is given the list and the id, aswell as what need to go before and after it in the full link
        }

        
        
        var x = 'no';
        var childs = put.childNodes;
        if(put.classList.contains('lowtobig')){
            for (i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                if(prodlist['prod'+childs[i].id][array_price] > prodlist[id][array_price]){
                    if(x == 'no'){
                        x = i;
            }}}
            if(x !== 'no'){
                put.insertBefore(productParentDiv, put.children[x]);
            }else{
                put.appendChild(productParentDiv);
            }
        }
        else if(put.classList.contains('bigtolow')){
            for (i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                //console.log(childs[i].id);
                if(prodlist['prod'+childs[i].id][array_price] < prodlist[id][array_price]){
                    if(x == 'no'){
                        x = i;
            }}}
            if(x !== 'no'){
                put.insertBefore(productParentDiv, put.children[x]);
            }else{
                put.appendChild(productParentDiv);
            }
        }
        else{
            put.appendChild(productParentDiv);
        }

        //adds primery product button to product parent div
        var productPrimeryA = document.createElement('a');
        productPrimeryA.classList = 'productPrimeryA';
        productPrimeryA.href = 'product.php?product='+prodlist[id][array_id];
        productParentDiv.appendChild(productPrimeryA);
            //name
            var name = document.createElement('p');
            name.classList = 'name';
            name.innerHTML = prodlist[id][array_name].toUpperCase();
            productPrimeryA.appendChild(name);
            //price
            var cost = document.createElement('p');
            cost.classList = 'cost';
            cost.innerHTML = formatter.format(prodlist[id][array_price]/100)
            //cost.innerHTML = '£'+prodlist[id][array_price].toUpperCase()/100;
            productPrimeryA.appendChild(cost);
        //colors
        var colorrow = document.createElement('div');
        colorrow.classList = 'colorgroupproductview';
        productParentDiv.appendChild(colorrow);
            //color
            var color_array = [];
            var count = 0;
            for(const subprod in prodlist){
                if (prodlist[subprod][array_name] == prodlist[id][array_name] &&  prodlist[subprod][array_stock]>0 && prodlist[subprod][array_type] == prodlist[id][array_type] && prodlist[subprod][array_gender] == prodlist[id][array_gender]){
                    var currentcolor = prodlist[subprod][array_color];
                    if(color_array.indexOf(currentcolor) == -1){
                        color_array.push(prodlist[subprod][array_color]);

                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            var color_array = [];
            if(count > 1){
                for(const subprod in prodlist){
                    if (prodlist[subprod][array_name] == prodlist[id][array_name] &&  prodlist[subprod][array_stock]>0 && prodlist[subprod][array_type] == prodlist[id][array_type] && prodlist[subprod][array_gender] == prodlist[id][array_gender]){
                        var currentcolor = prodlist[subprod][array_color];
                        if(color_array.indexOf(currentcolor) == -1){
                            color_array.push(prodlist[subprod][array_color]);
                            var color = document.createElement('a');
                            if(prodlist[subprod][array_color] == prodlist[id][array_color]){
                                color.classList = 'colorselprod colorselprodactive'
                            }else{
                                color.classList = 'colorselprod';
                            }
                            color.href = 'product.php?product='+prodlist[subprod][array_id];
                            color.innerHTML = '0';
                            color.style.backgroundColor = prodlist[subprod][array_color].toUpperCase();
                            color.style.color = prodlist[subprod][array_color];
                            colorrow.appendChild(color);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

does this help at all?

bellow is the result of the php near the top that loads in the collecion of arrays

```
prodlist = {prod1 : ["1","y","killer bunny hoodie","vintage films (japanese)","joggers","U","m","#ffffff","2750","N","0","#9D1A1A","#0C0C0C","A sturdy and warm sweatshirt bound to keep you warm in the colder months. A pre-shrunk, classic fit sweater that's made with air-jet spun yarn for a soft feel and reduced pilling."],prod2 : ["2","n","killer bunny hoodie","vintage films (japanese)","joggers","U","s","#ffffff","2750","N","10","#9D1A1A","#0C0C0C","A sturdy and warm sweatshirt bound to keep you warm in the colder months. A pre-shrunk, classic fit sweater that's made with air-jet spun yarn for a soft feel and reduced pilling."],prod29 : ["29","y","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","m","#000000","6000","T","10","#7F6444","#1B1B1B","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod30 : ["30","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","s","#000000","6000","T","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod31 : ["31","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","l","#000000","6000","T","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod32 : ["32","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","xl","#000000","6000","T","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod33 : ["33","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","m","#72717f","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod34 : ["34","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","s","#72717f","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod35 : ["35","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","l","#72717f","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod36 : ["36","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","xl","#72717f","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod37 : ["37","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","m","#314687","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod38 : ["38","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","s","#314687","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod39 : ["39","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","l","#314687","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod40 : ["40","n","IMPERIAL HOMEWORLD","BRITISH SPACE FORCE","coat","U","xl","#314687","6000","V","10","","","this coat is market with the royal home world badge, a symbol of solidarity and bravery in defence of the crown and its dominions. this crest originates from the early expeditionary forces that set out across the stars in the name of his majestys vision for a free and British universe.  "],prod41 : ["41","y","PRINT TEST HOODIE","PRINT TEST","HOODIE","U","m","#ffffff","5500","","10","","","This comfy unisex hoodie has a soft outside with a vibrant print, and an even softer brushed fleece inside. The hoodie has a relaxed fit, and its perfect for wrapping yourself into on a chilly evening."],prod42 : ["42","n","PRINT TEST HOODIE","PRINT TEST","HOODIE","U","xs","#ffffff","5500","","10","","","This comfy unisex hoodie has a soft outside with a vibrant print, and an even softer brushed fleece inside. The hoodie has a relaxed fit, and its perfect for wrapping yourself into on a chilly evening."],prod43 : ["43","n","PRINT TEST HOODIE","PRINT TEST","HOODIE","U","s","#ffffff","5500","","10","","","This comfy unisex hoodie has a soft outside with a vibrant print, and an even softer brushed fleece inside. The hoodie has a relaxed fit, and its perfect for wrapping yourself into on a chilly evening."],prod44 : ["44","n","PRINT TEST HOODIE","PRINT TEST","HOODIE","U","l","#ffffff","5500","","10","","","This comfy unisex hoodie has a soft outside with a vibrant print, and an even softer brushed fleece inside. The hoodie has a relaxed fit, and its perfect for wrapping yourself into on a chilly evening."],prod45 : ["45","n","PRINT TEST HOODIE","PRINT TEST","HOODIE","U","xl","#ffffff","5500","","10","","","This comfy unisex hoodie has a soft outside with a vibrant print, and an even softer brushed fleece inside. The hoodie has a relaxed fit, and its perfect for wrapping yourself into on a chilly evening."],prod61 : ["61","y","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","m","#000000","2500","P","10","#AA3636","#324666","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod62 : ["62","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","xs","#000000","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod63 : ["63","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","s","#000000","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod64 : ["64","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","l","#000000","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod65 : ["65","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","xl","#000000","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod66 : ["66","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","m","#ffffff","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod67 : ["67","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","xs","#ffffff","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod68 : ["68","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","s","#ffffff","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod69 : ["69","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","l","#ffffff","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod70 : ["70","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","xl","#ffffff","2500","","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod71 : ["71","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","m","#292929","2500","V","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod72 : ["72","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","xs","#292929","2500","V","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod73 : ["73","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","M","xs","#292929","2500","V","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod74 : ["74","n","PRINT TEST EMBROIDERED T-SHIRT","PRINT TEST","t-shirt","U","l","#292929","2500","V","10","","","a simple t-shirt embroidered with this complex red design that resembles a print text mark. "],prod76 : ["76","y","Crimson Embroidered J…
```

the key peaces of code...

```
        //this is the current method for testing to find and then load in the images
    if(doesFileExist('assets/hero_images/'+prodlist[id][array_id]+'.png')){  //returns a true of false if the file matching the varaibale exists
        productParentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/hero_images/"+prodlist[id][array_id]+".png')"; //if it does its made the background
    }else{
        productParentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+findreplace(prodlist,id,"assets/hero_images/",".png")+"')"; //sets it to be the resault of the function findreplace() that is given the list and the id, aswell as what need to go before and after it in the full link
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code has numerous syntactical issues before even getting to all the design problems. It'd be helpful if you could provide working code and a refactor attempt, otherwise it's just too much to fix all at once. Thanks.